# Legality of Embedding Games From Other Websites On My Website

Tags: united-states, internet, licensing

Is it legal to embed flash games from other websites on my website? So far I've only embedded open-source games with MIT or similar licenses.

What if a game on another website doesn't have any license shown?

The way it works is their game is not "hosted" or "stored" on my website, it's just embedded directly from their website in a frame on my website. Exactly the same process as embedding a YouTube video on your website.

I've googled and read everything I could, but it seems fairly open ended.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't seen that. So, basically, it depends on the courts interpretation?
Wonder if there's anything I can do to make things less risky, like cite my source: under the iframe or anything?

Comment: Best to ask permission of the source. Even sites with no license or TOS have default copyright (somewhat depending on jurisdiction).